# Can not compile Arduino code with Atmel registers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-uno

I am using the VSCode editor with the Arudino extension installed. Basically, I have a simple program where I calling a function that will setup a timer for 5 ms and then run. However, in the editor, I am getting the error:

"error: 'OCR3A' was not declared in this scope"

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

I should note that intellisense can see the definitions for the registers. I am also using the Arduino Uno R3 board. Also, here is the code:

```
void isr_int1(void) {
    if(TCCR3B == 0)// Debug code if the timer is not running
    {
        startTimerValue = millis();

        TCNT3 = 0;
        OCR3A = 5000;
        sei();

        bitSet(TCCR3B, WGM32);
        bitSet(TCCR3B, CS31);
        bitSet(TIMSK3, OCIE3A);

        detachInterrupt(1);
    }
}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect)
{
    TCCR3A = 0;
    TCCR3B = 0
    TCNT3 = 0;
    OCR3A = 0;

    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(millis() - startTimerValue);

    attachInterrupt(1, isr_int1, FALLING);
}

void loop()
{
    isr_int1();
}
```

Comment: So if you locate where they're defined - and put the #include to that file at the top - does it fix things?

Comment: It does not. I do have the #include in the source of where they are defined. Technically, the avr library prefers that you use avr/io.h and then #define the chip (which I have done). That include the correct header file.

Comment: Arduino is weird. It's some hand-holdy "version" of C++ that tries to manage the dependencies for you in a "sketch". I've never used the visual studio extensions. But can you make sure your proper board is selected? And make sure to #include <Arduino.h> at the top?

Comment: Yes, Arduino.h is defined at the top and the Uno board is selected

Comment: Also, I should note that I tested this in the Arduino IDE and the build also failed

Comment: Ok, so here is another data point, when I change the reference from timer 3 to timer 1, the project builds. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the Arduino UNO doesn't have `Timer/Counter 3` as it uses `ATMega328A`. The `T/C 3` is available for example on Adruino Micro/Leonardo (based on `ATMega32U4`) and Arduino MEGA 2560 (`ATMega2560`).

And different MCUs also might have different register names. That's why the Arduino Core is full of `#ifdefs`

Also you might be getting those error because of wrong target MCU.

At least it usually perfectly corresponds with register names used in MCUs datasheet. It's also the first place you should study when you are trying to configure something on your own.